# dplyr::select question: different selection according to the order in which variables are picked

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a very simple question, I guess. Please find two dplyr::select commands here below. I am using the nycflights13::flights dataset. The first command gives me what I was expecting. I would have expected the second one to render the same thing, but it does not. It looks as if it pays not attention to the ":" part. Any hints?
Thanks!

```
select(flights,dep_delay:arr_delay,-arr_time)

select(flights,-arr_time, dep_delay:arr_delay)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second case, when we specify `-arr_time` before the range of columns, it is selecting all columns except the `-arr_time`, and then the `dep_delay:arr_delay` is just redundant, whereas in first case, it is already subsetting columns from `dep_delay:arr_delay` first

```
names(select(flights,dep_delay:arr_delay))
#[1] "dep_delay"      "arr_time"       "sched_arr_time" "arr_delay"
```

and from this, we are removing the `arr_time`

In the second, it would remove `-arr_time` among all the columns

```
names(select(flights,-arr_time))
#[1] "year"           "month"          "day"            "dep_time"       "sched_dep_time" "dep_delay"      "sched_arr_time" "arr_delay"     
#[9] "carrier"        "flight"         "tailnum"        "origin"         "dest"           "air_time"       "distance"       "hour"          
#[17] "minute"         "time_hour"
```

then it reintroduces the `arr_time` because it is part of the range

```
names(select(flights,-arr_time, dep_delay:arr_delay))
#[1] "year"           "month"          "day"            "dep_time"       "sched_dep_time" "dep_delay"      "sched_arr_time" "arr_delay"     
#[9] "carrier"        "flight"         "tailnum"        "origin"         "dest"           "air_time"       "distance"       "hour"          
#[17] "minute"         "time_hour"      "arr_time"
```